# How is eMMC 'permanent write-protection' implemented?

Tags: storage, sd-card

According to [this document](http://zedboard.org/sites/default/files/documentations/EBU%20eMMC%20Security%20rev1.1%20-%20Non%20Confidential.pdf), it appears that eMMC devices can be put into a 'permanent write-protection' mode, either for the entire device or a limited area, by sending certain commands programmatically to the device. Apparently, once that is done, that portion of the device is read-only and the operation cannot be reversed.

**My questions are:**

- How is this feature implemented?
- Surely, if some bits in a register can be set by a command, then it should also be possible to unset them?
- Is it really not possible to 'undo' this 'permanent write-protect' of an eMMC device?

Comment: If properly designed, even a solution implemented purely “in firmware” can be irreversible.

Comment: @DanielB could you provide some more details, or an example?

Comment: ? The firmware could of course refuse to reset the write-protect bit once set. It’s not as if you’re directly accessing some memory. You’re talking to a computer.

Answer (score 2):

The general principles of this are quite simple but the details are known only to the manufacturer. There are no standards that specify how internal operations are performed and the manufacturer is under no obligation to provide such details. Details that are provided are limited at best.

A modern storage device can be considered a "Black Box". What the device does is known but exactly how it works is unknown. We cannot see into the device to determine how it works. All we know is what the manufacturer chooses to tell us.

The purpose of an eMMC device is to store data. Commands have been provided to read and write blocks of data and a number of other things. It is important to understand that nothing that happens in the device can be controlled or even influenced unless some means of doing this has been provided. Such devices usually provide a means of temporarily making the device read only. The device may also provide a permanent read only option. It could be activated by sending the device a command or it could be set by the internal processor. There is likely some internal register that contains this information. But it is not directly controllable from outside the device. Only by using the provided command can it be activated.

Making the setting permanent could not be simpler. No extra hardware or software is necessary. All that needs to be done is to not provide a command to reset the read only mode. There is a command that could be named "Set read only mode". There is no corresponding command to reset the mode.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is a guess, but is is a possible method.

Every flash cell will have an "erase" data line which controls a set of circuitry designed to erase the block. That data line could would not normally need to draw high current so could be made relatively thin. Making it thin in one particular spot would effectively create a fuse.

Intentionally drawing too much current from that line would "blow" the fuse rendering the control line useless for it's original purpose. It would remove the erase line and make the block permanently unerasable, effectively read-only.

Depending on how the fuses are set up you could either blow the fuses for every block or a global erase line to write protect the entire device.

Blowing this fuse would be impossible to repair as it is embedded inside a block of silicon. There is no way to get to the silicon traces without irreparable damage to the device as a whole.